# Resolve a Kentico localisation macro in a transformation?

Tags: macros, kentico

As the title suggests I am trying to resolve a localisation string inside a repeater. I have a wysiwyg editor to input some html on the form tab of the document type, so the source would look like this

```
Field1: "<a href="test.aspx" title="test">{$localstring$}</a>"
```

Then in the transformation I have

```
<li><%# Eval("Field1") %></li>
```

This outputs the string as

- {$localstring$}

and doesn't resolve this as a macro and go lookup the localstring in the UI culture localisation.

I have tried different things including

```
<%# Eval(CMS.GlobalHelper.ResHelper.LocalizeString("Field1")) %>
```

and

```
<%# Eval(CMS.CMSHelper.CMSContext.CurrentResolver.ResolveMacros("Field1")) %>
```

all of which give the same output, can anyone point me in the right direction? I am sure it's the way Eval is being called.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is following:

```
<%# CMS.CMSHelper.CMSContext.CurrentResolver.ResolveMacros(Eval("Field1").ToString()) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

in case somebody else searches for this: if you want to use localization string `custom.my-string` in ASPX transformation, you should resolve it as follows:

```
<%# CMS.CMSHelper.CMSContext.CurrentResolver.ResolveMacros("{$custom.my-string$}") %>
```

note: no spaces! if you add spaces like this: "{$ custom.my-string $}" - it **WILL NOT** work.